# Installing OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I would like to start programming in OCaml. As I am a Windows user, I understand that it is preferred to do so using the OCaml plugin for Netbeans.

I have downloaded the aforementioned plugin from the following link: http://ocamlplugin.loki-a.com/ocamlplugin/updates/ . I have installed the plugin into Netbeans as instructed. I managed to open a project but even the sample "Hello World" won't run.

I then tried to install the OCaml IDE from here: http://ocamlplugin.loki-a.com/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download_2 , but it still wouldn't run anything.

I am not interested in working with Eclipse because that would include downloading Cygwin.

I would appreciate a simple solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: I haven't heard of any preferred windows IDE; esp netbeans. I recently installed OCaml for the mingw toolchain with no issues. Your issue seems to be interacting with the IDE, but have you installed OCaml tool-chain yet?

Comment: It sounds like you have not instaled OCaml itself, only plugins for an IDE.

Comment: In addition, I found this guide to be great when deciding how to install the windows OCaml compiler - http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-4.00/notes/README.win32

Comment: AFAIK any workable OCaml on windows require cygwin.

Comment: The MSVC binary of OCaml does not require Cygwin, but does require it to compile ocaml from source --see the guide I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest OCaIDE under Eclipse, if you stick to Windows anyway.
But I don't understand your reluctancy to use cygwin, especially when there is such nice [step-by-step tutorial](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/tutorials.php) for configuring cygwin for OcaIDE and Eclipse.

Another option, which I haven't tried but would strongly suggest you trying, is Sublime Text 2. It supports OCaml and is a very popular cross-platform text editor. But since I haven't tried it, I would not be able to provide you with details about it. Although it comes with a cost, you can evaluate it for free without time limit.

TypeRex has been my favourite for OCaml so far, and you can now use Emacs in Windows, so with some workaround in cygwin you can use TypeRex in Windows.
Another option is to use VirtualBox, install a normal linux distro and use Typerex+Emacs inside it. It is also not complicated, as it takes 1 hour to config at most.

Comment: I don't think that Sublime Text 2 provide any kind of code completion, but iirc it does syntax coloring.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have finally installed exlipse with cygwin. however, since i have never used exlpise before I have some problems with running my programs. can you recomend me about a guide for using exlips for ocaml?

Comment: Finish [this](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/tutorials.php) first. If you feel like you need to learn more about Eclipse, google a tutorial. There are lots of Eclipse tutorials online, find the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

The ocaml links that you gave have not been touched since 2009 (4 years ago). That probably means the odds of them running with the current NetBeans are equivalent to the proverbial sphere of solidified water in the Christian place of eternal theological punishment.

Since you are asking about running under Cygwin, it sounds like you want a Linux version of Eclipse as well. Eclipse runs quite well under Win7, at least, and under Mint (I use them under both) However, all my attempts to get ANY OCaml IDE running under either system have been borged (resistance is futile, and depends and capacitance anyway).

So, under Mint 15, emacs and vim (the old standards) work well as text editors. I wish I could suggest anything else.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

By now, another option has appeared for Windows 10 users wanting to use OCaml: the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide).

Basically, what it does is that it allows you to run Bash and any non-GUI Linux program on your PC. Once installed, you can install OCaml and OPAM with `apt-get` and you're good to go.

As far as I am concerned, I use Windows 10 on my desktop PC, and I haven't had any inconvenience with WSL yet.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Merlin/... which is are plugins for emacs. But I can understand that you dont want to use emacs. I have been told that the support with Visual Studio Code is supposed to be quite good, especially when using it together with the builtin console. Also for smaller things there is [Ocamltop](https://www.typerex.org/ocaml-top.html) but I have now idea how the Windows support is. In the end I suggest, using the Linux Shell on Windows as RichouHunter suggests.